# How to run the rest xml request in jemeter and how to configure the tomcat keystore

Tags: ssl-certificate, jmeter, http-authentication

I'm the newbee to the jmeter. I want to run same REst xml test cases run by the soapui. I need to know to  do user/password configuration and tomcat keystore configuration for ssl enabled(https) request. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to configure HTTP Basic authentication with JMeter, you can add in your thread group `HTTP Authorization Manager` element, if you select this element you can see the baseUrl, user and password fields, fill it with your server data.

To configure SSL to provide a client certificate to authenticate with JMeter, you can use `KeyStore Configuration` element. You need to generate a `JKS` keystore with your client keys, then add this java options to the java call to start your JMeter : `-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=path_to_keystore` `-Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=password_of_keystore` in order to reference your keystore. Then to use this keystore you only have to configure `Alias start index` and `Alias end index` in `KeyStore Configuration` element (if your keystore contains only 1 key you can put `0`on both parameters).

Here there is the JMeter user's guide to [`KeyStore Configuration`](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Keystore_Configuration) and [`HTTP Authoritzation manager`](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Authorization_Manager).

Hope this helps,